# Can postfix be set up to forward mail to multiple recipients

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server

I have the following postfix `virtual` file:

```
test@domain.com bob@me.com
```

This correctly forwards all emails to `test@domain.com` to `bob@me.com`

However I would like to forward these emails to `bob2@me.com` as well.

I tried this change and it does not seem to work:

```
test@domain.com bob@me.com
test@domain.com bob2@me.com
```

How do I tell postfix to forward all emails to multiple recipients?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Put all your addresses on the same line separated by commas as explained in the [Postfix manual for virtual](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html).

```
test@domain.com bob@me.com,bob2@me.com
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: is it possible to do this entire domains somehow? I tried `@xyz.com @xyz.net, @xyz.org`, but it didn't work

Comment: I have the same question @MohamedHafez , I can't find a way to send the catch all emails to 2 mailboxes. Did you find a solution?

Comment: A separate line/directive for each domain should work:
`@xyz.com bob@me.com,bob2@me.com`\n
`xyz.org bob@me.com,bob2@me.com` should work - but comments don't allow new lines so replace the \n with a newline!

Answer (score 1):

You can make alias on multiply addresses and setup a bcc for that alias:

Find or edit bcc_map (or else name) file in /etc/postfix, compile this into a postfix hash file using:

```
postmap bcc_map
```

Add tp postfix main.cf config:

```
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc_map
```