# How do I automatically BCC received mail to multiple users in Postfix?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix, email-server

I am trying to link up a dummy email address to two different email addresses:
`contact@example.com` -> `user1@example.com` and `user2@example.com`
This would mean that mail sent to `contact@example.com` would also get BCC'd or forwarded to `user1@example.com` and `user2@example.com`

I am having trouble with the `recipient_bbc_maps` config:

```
# /etc/postfix/main.cf
recipient_bcc_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_map
```

```
# /etc/postfix/recipient_bbc_map
## This works
/^contact@example\.com$/ user1@example.com

## This doesn't work
/^contact@example\.com$/ user1@example.com,user2@example.com
```

The suggestion was taken from https://serverfault.com/a/183491, but it doesn't work.
Postfix can receive and send messages, so I know that my config is good so far.
What am I doing wrong?

```
# /var/log/mail.log
postfix/qmgr[594770]: 309D64800B2: from=<sender@gmail.com>, size=3250, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
postfix/local[594799]: 309D64800B2: to=<contact@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
postfix/local[594799]: 309D64800B2: to=<user1@example.com, user2>, orig_to=<user1@example.com,user2@example.com>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.3, status=bounced (bad address syntax)
postfix/qmgr[594770]: 309D64800B2: removed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear:

```
orig_to=<user1@example.com,user2@example.com>
bad address syntax
```

You cannot specify multiple addresses in a bcc-maps.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537523/postfix-recipient-bcc-maps-multiple-recipients-how-to
explains how to workaround this feature:

- create a virtual map to have the distribution list ;
- send BCC to the vmap

The Bcc will be expanded to the whole distribution list

```
#/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps
source@domain.tld    rcpt@domain.tld


#/etc/postfix/vmaps
rcpt@domain.tld    rcpt1@domain.tld,rcpt2.domain.tld,rcpt3@domain.tld
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that virtual aliases can do this!

Comment: De nada :) Maps are often evil.